# Is there a way to set multiple values in one variable in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am a newbie in coding.

Here is what I did:

```
DECALRE @v VARCHAR(100)

SET @v = (SELECT TOP 100 NAMES FROM TestTable WITH(NOLOCK))

SELECT @v AS SampleData
```

But it returned an error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Are there any way to set multiple values in one variable in SQL Server 2008?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While I am not saying it is definitely wrong to use `NOLOCK` in this situation. It is probably unnecessary. It seems to have gained a reputation as a magic performance fix, and this is not really the case. It should be used very carefully. For more reading see [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/),

Comment: Interesting info thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one type of variable *designed* for holding multiple values. It's called a table variable:

```
declare @v table (Name varchar(100) not null)

insert into @v(Name )
select top 100 name from TestTable /* no ORDER BY means this is ill-defined */
```

You can insert/update/delete in this table variable and query from it via `select`s in exactly the same way as any other table.

Note though that this looks like you're breaking things down into "procedural" steps - first I'll get the top 100 names, then I'll do X, then I'll do Y. In SQL, you should try to put as much as possible into single queries, and leave it to the *optimizer* to determine what order to do things in, which subresults should be stored, etc.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to use the declared variable in IF satement ?
 ex. 
IF(SELECT ContactNo FROM TestTable WHERE Names in(@v)) IS NULL 
BEGIN 
END

Comment: @bobsponge - you can, but you have to treat it *as* a table. So it would be `... IN (SELECT Name from @v) ...`

Comment: @bobsponge - thanks. Since you're new here, you may want to read our help page on [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)